# Different kinds of variable initialization

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of various type initialization in C++ and what is the correct one?

```
int i1 = 1;
int i2(1);
int i3{};
int i4 = {1};
int i5 = int{1};
```

Comment: Who claimed that there was a unique correct choice?

Comment: If you want the value to be 0, option 3 is the correct one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### `int i1 = 1;`

This is good old C style.  Still works fine and is conventional in C++.

#### `int i2(1);`

This is C++ style.  It came about because some types need more than one argument to their constructor.

#### `int i3{};`

C++11 style.

#### `int i4 = {1};`

This is not conventional.

#### `int i5 = int{1};`

This is not conventional.  But it's supported due to the new "uniform initialization syntax" of C++11.

#### `int i6 = {};`

You didn't ask about this one, but it's also valid in C++11.

#### `int i7{1};`

Another bonus, this is probably the most conventional use of uniform initialization syntax in C++11.

#### `auto i8 = int{1};`

Thanks to KerrekSB for this abomination, which he credits to none other than Herb Sutter.  This will probably win you friends from the "No True Modern C++" camp, and alienate your coworkers who were perfectly happy with the first syntax.

Comment: You forgot `auto i8 = int{1};` -- Sutter style.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Great, added that!

Comment: So do you think that the reason why these different options exist is mainly historical, or are there cases where one of these has significant advantages?

Comment: Doesn't explain the purpose, even though the list itself is already a bit helpfull. What does `int i = {};` do?

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Arguably the original C++ way of `int i2(1)` was a mistake and should always have been `int i2{1}` which is now known as Uniform Initialization in C++11.  As for why there are so many options, it's because of this: https://xkcd.com/927/ .  The old way reminds people of C and doesn't work for certain types; the newest ways don't work with old compilers and will scare some people off (the majority of C++ programmers have probably never used C++11 Uniform Initialization).

Comment: Note that there are situations in which `T t (1)` and `T t {1}` will do different things. `std::vector`, for instance.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think Herb Sutter actually prefers `auto i8 = 1;`, which does not explicitly write `int`. Who knows, maybe I get it wrong.

Comment: @NickyC This will lead to conflicts: `signed` or `unsigned`? `int` or `long` or `long long`?

Comment: @CinCout No, it won't. `auto i8 = 1` is `int`, `auto i9 = 1LL` is `long long`, `auto i10 = 1UL` is `unsigned long`, etc. Well, it is confusing, I know.

Comment: _"Thanks to KerrekSB for this abomination, which he credits to none other than Herb Sutter"_ :D :D :D

Comment: What's the difference between `int i8{1}` and `auto i8 = int{1};` actually?

Comment: @quantumbit: Practically speaking there is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** - Use `X a1 {v};` for initialization.

To take cue from [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) himself, below is directly quoted from TCPL, fourth edition -

> If an initializer is specified for an object, that initializer determines the initial value of an object.
>   An initializer can use one of four syntactic styles:

```
X a1 {v};
X a2 = {v};
X a3 = v;
X a4(v);
```

> **Of these, only the first can be used in every context, and I strongly recommend its use**. It is clearer
>   and less error-prone than the alternatives. However, the first form (used for a1) is new in C++11, so
>   the other three forms are what you find in older code. The two forms using = are what you use in
>   C.

Comment: Unfortunately the uniform initialization is not fully uniform. `std::vector<int> v1(1, 2);`and `std::vector<int> v2{1, 2};` will do different things.

Comment: So if I have s type with 2 params in constructor, the `type(1, 3)` calls constructor of `type` with 2 parameters like a function call: `ctor(1, 3)`, but what `type{1, 2}` does?